# Old Joomla site returns bool(false) in browser after server move

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, boolean, boolean-expression

I have moved to a new server, and intend to update this old Joomla site to current version. Currently on Joomla 1.5.26

I initially had an installation/index.php redirect loop after removing the installation directory displaying a 404 error (configuration.php was writable and contained the correct information). In order to attempt to fix this error, I added:

```
var_dump(file_exists(JPATH_CONFIGURATION.DS.'configuration.php'));
```

to administrator/includes/define.php

and I changed lines 23 - 32 in administrator/framework.php

```
if (file_exists(JPATH_INSTALLATION.'/index.php')) {
header('Location: '.substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],   'index.php')).JPATH_INSTALLATION.'/index.php');
```

Now, the web page (www.chesterandcrick.com) is displaying bool(false) in the browser, and I can still access the administrator section.

I'm frustrated and confused now and I'd really appreciate any advice or suggestions that anyone has. Also happy to pay for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `var_dump()` is returning the boolean. And as you have sent that to the browser you can no longer successfully execute a `header()` as output has been sent.

Remove the `var_dump(file_exists(JPATH_CONFIGURATION.DS.'configuration.php'));` and it may well start working again, assuming you completed the move correctly.

If you really need to see the output from the `file_exists()` write it to a file like this

```
$x = file_exists(JPATH_CONFIGURATION.DS.'configuration.php') ? 'Exists' : 'Does not exist';
file_put_content('debug.txt', $x);
```

Then you will not have written output to the browser, and check the result using FTP or whatever you use to see the web site directories.